# How can I construct a new object out of these properties?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce

So, this is my object:

```
const data = [ { 
    main: 7,
    second: 2
    otherData: 'some string'
 } ]
```

**I need to make a new object out of particular properties, so in the end it should look like:**

```
const newData = {
    7: {
     second: 2
    }
  }
```

I have tried to solve it using `.reduce()`, but can't figure out how to omit some properties.

```
const newData = data.reduce((obj, curr, index) => {
  return {
    ..obj, [index]: curr
  };
}, {});
```

produces:

```
{ '0':
   { main: 7,
     second: 3
   } 
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Not the original downvoter, but I have downvoted your question, too, for a simple reason -- if you cannot explain your problem, there is no good solution. To be constructive -- can you *describe* the *general* relationship between your input object and output object?

Comment: Yet, it was solved..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're conflating arrays and objects. If I understand correctly, what you want is this:

```
const newData = data.map(obj => {
  return {
    [obj.main]: {
      second: obj.second
    }
  };
});
```

Given your sample input of

```
const data = [ { 
    main: 7,
    second: 2
    otherData: 'some string'
 } ];
```

This will give back

```
[
  {
    7: {
      second: 2
    }
  }
]
```

### Update from comment

Sounds like you do actually want reduce here. Use this:

```
const reduced = data.reduce((acc, {main, second}, index) => {
  acc[main] = {second, index};
  return acc;
}, {});
```

Which for your sample input gives

```
{
  '7': {
    second: 2,
    index: 0
  }
}
```

Note that as I said below be careful because an object with the same `main` as a previous one *will* overwrite the earlier entry.

Comment: @dututu yes in the sense that all the array operations like `map` and `filter` can be defined in terms of a fold, but why? It would be more code, run slower/use more memory, and be less readable.

Comment: I need object, not array as final output.

Comment: @dututu so you have an array of objects, and you want to compress it to a single object. You do indeed want `reduce` then. Are all the entries unique? What if there's a conflict (e.g. two objects in the array have the same value for main?)

Comment: Not sure if they will be unique. I now receive something like: `[
  {
    7: {
      second: 2
    }
  }
]` but I need to receive something like:  `{
    7: {
     second: 2
    }
  }` Sorry for bad formatting.

Comment: @dututu that's fine, but if you can't guarantee uniqueness then you'll need some collision resolution scheme. Otherwise any objects with the same `main` property will overwrite each other in the reducing process.

Comment: Thanks. Can this function somehow be extended to achieve this: `data.reduce((obj, curr, index) => {
  return {
    ..obj, [index]: curr
  };
}, {});`?

Comment: @dututu it can, but that doesn't match the sample output you provided in the question. You're hashing based on array index which is fine, but in your example output you're hashing on the object property `main`. Please edit the question so it's clear what you want.

Comment: Your solution works, I asked the last one just to see if we can out-scale it somehow. If you have time please write, I will mark this as done anyhow. :)

Comment: @dututu I added an index. If it works for you please accept my answer (little green checkmark next to it).

Answer (score 0):

Reduce me hod is called upon an array.
In your case, you only have a single object in the array.
So '0' represents the '[@index]' and your only cild object is mapped to 'curr'

Answer (score -1):

Instead of reduce you can try forEach, like below

```
let retData = {};


data.forEach(({ main, second }) => {
retData[main] = {second};
});
```

In this particular case the output will be:

```
retData = {
 7: {
      second: 2
    }
}
```